CiviDiscount & Percentage Price Field Order of Extensions
When I give people a discount code, they are being charged 3% of the pre-discounted rate.  This is particularly obvious on 100% scholarships where they should not have to pay anything. Note that in this situation the convenience fee is required not optional.
Per this https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20639 I see that the order of installation may help, but is not perfect solution.
I guess I can try uninstalling  and reinstall Percentage Price Field so it would end up after CiviDiscount, but I don't know if I want to do that right now with registration underway.
Right now my workaround is to refund people their nominal % payment, but that is clearly not ideal!

pls link to the extension you are using

there is also https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.extrafee

Thanks!  Here are the links: https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.percentagepricesetfield
and https://civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount

you could try the extrafee extension instead
